# How to wrap function that takes unlimited number of arguments

Tags: php, argument-passing

I want to wrap an existing function that takes unlimited number of arguments, 
e.g. this is the existing function:

```
function T()
{
    $args = func_num_args();
    // Do stuff with arguments.
}
```

I now want to wrap it, e.g.

```
/*
 * This function shall also take unlimited arguments,
 * and just pass them on to T().
 */
function myT()
{
    // TODO: Take all arguments and pass them on to T().
    $result = T();

    // Do stuff with the result of T().
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to pass the unlimited arguments on to `T()` in `myT()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `call_user_func_array()` (http://php.net/call_user_func_array)

```
$res = call_user_func_array("T", func_get_args());
```